# What is a good naming convention for classes in an inheritance chain?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have three classes in an inheritance chain:

```
AddActorUITests : WebTestBase : IntegrationTestBase
```

However I would somehow like to signal by naming convention that `WebTestBase` inherits from `IntegrationTestBase` so that the developer writing code in `AddActorUITests` does not have to check `WebTestBase`to verify that it inherits from `IntegrationTestBase`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `WebIntegrationTestBase` - a bit of a no-brainer TBH!

Comment: `AddActorUiTests` : `WebIntegrationTest` : `IntegrationTest`. Please also drop `*Base` suffix, if name is generic enough then you don't need it (and  you can't instantiate it because it's abstract).

Comment: There isn't really any actually. Normally an inheritance gets its parent name added behind/front (like `Card` and `TarotCard` or `DbContext` and `OracleDbContext`. But it is not always the case (like `Animal` and `Cat` or `ActivityBase` and `Sailing`)).

Comment: Teach the developer hovering their mouse cursor for 500 msec over the `WebTestBase` identifier for a documentation pop-up to show up. #problemsolved

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Will definitely drop the base suffix!

Comment: Naming conventions are not opinion based? Who uses this.field instead of _field these days? Thats stupid.

Comment: @Jamiec A no-brainer it is indeed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Inheritance is about `is-a` relationship between the classes. Inheritance should be easy to tell without having to use some kind of convention in the naming.

For instance if you have a `Dog` which inherits `Animal` you don't name it `DogAnimal`. It's already easy to understand what a dog is. Let's look at it from the other perspective. When you code against the `Dog` class, why is it so important to know that it's an `Animal` that you need to indicate it in the name? Hungarian notation was abandoned for a reason.

If you still need that notation, aren't you more using inheritance as a toolbox. i.e. you do inheritance just to get some nice features into the sub classes? In that case it's much better that you use composition.

Comment: Yes, composition over inheritance! However I have a giant setup with static and non-static properties and helper methods. I'm trying to do more of composition but it is not always possible with my setup.

Comment: With your cherry picked example, it is indeed not necessary. But contriving something more tangible `Component`, `ContainerComponent` for example it *is* common to follow the name down so that you can tell that a 'ContainerComponent` is a specialisation of `Component`.

Comment: I don't agree. Take for instance Winforms. All controls are called `TextBox`, `ComboBox` etc instead of `TextBoxControl`, even though all UI components inherits `Control`. Which popular library are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `Visual Studio` you can use comments?

```
/// <summary>
/// Inherit <see cref="IntegrationTestBase"> class
/// </summary>
class WebTestBase : IntegrationTestBase
{
    ...
}
```

and when the user types out the `WebTestBase`, `Visual Studio` will automatic show the comments in a popout message.